# Solving set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
pa_0 + (1-p)a_2&=&a_1\\
pa_1 + (1-p)a_3&=&a_2\\
pa_2 + (1-p)a_4&=&a_3\\
pa_3 + (1-p)a_0&=&a_4\\
pa_4 + (1-p)a_1&=&a_0\\
a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4&=&1\\
\end{array}
$$

$$0 < p < 1$$
$$0 < a_n < 1$$

How do you solve the set of equations for all the $a_n$ variables?

Comment: I got stuck due to p, the coefficient which is not fixed in [0,1].

Comment: add the first 5 equations listed (starting at the top) and use the 6th equation to simplify the resulting equation. Nevermind... everything cancels in that case.

Comment: Actually, $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 1/5$ is always a solution for any value of $p \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Adriano: Why does only o=0.5 work?

Comment: @JimmyK4542: yes. you r rght. Im not sure whether 0.2 is the one for this set of equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the system $S$ of the first five equations $pa_{i-1} + (1 - p)a_{i+1} = a_i$. Since $S$ is clearly invariant under the map $a_i \to a_i + t$ for any fixed $t$, assume without loss of generality that $a_0 = 0$. It's then easy to verify that the only solution of $S$ is $a_i = 0$ for all $i$. Thus the general solution to $S$ is given by $a_i \to t$ for some fixed $t$, and the only solution to the entire given system is $a_i = \frac{1}{5}$ for all $i$.

Comment: I can not understand the map you built, that is $a_i$ → $a_i$ + t. Can you explain it?

Comment: Replace $a_i$ with $a_i + t$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I mean what's the relationship between the map and p$a_{i−1}$ +(1−p)$a_{i+1}$ = $a_i$?

Comment: Like I said, that equation is invariant under the map.

Comment: make sense a lot

Comment: Much appreciate  ^_^